# python -w option (warning) doesn't work for 'once'

Tags: python, command-line, warnings

I'm using django 1.10, python 3.5.3

I'm trying to use the warning option to show warnings only once.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W%20documentation) if I use 'once' it shows every warning only once. It doesn't seems to work.
I've tried 'ignore' and it worked. I can also tell that it recognizes the option since I didn't get any warning about the value. (If you put some unrecognized value you get a warning at the beginning).
I actually use PYTHONWARNINGS environment variable but it should be the same.
Any idea?

Comment: What's the exact value you set? That is, if you run `echo $PYTHONWARNINGS` in your terminal, what does it print?

Comment: @JamesBennett once

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using `once` as the value for `PYTHONWARNINGS`, some warnings will still be automatically hidden by default, which may be why you don't see them (`PendingDeprecationWarning` and `DeprecationWarning`, for example, are hidden by default).

To see those, you need to explicitly tell Python to show them to you. Try something like `once::DeprecationWarning` instead.

Comment: when saying it's not working I meant  I see the warnings multiple times, same as earlier, and not just once.